# what does [][]*datatype mean in golang

Tags: go

Suppose this is my sample code. On running it outputs `[[]][[] []][[] [] []][[] [] [] []]`. Help me in understanding what this code is depicting and what is routingtable [][]*node called in programming terminology. Is it a slice of slice of node or is it a 2d array of node type. Forgive me if I sound dumb but I am just trying to learn.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type node struct {
    id int
}

func main() {
    var routingtable [][]*node

    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        routingtable = append(routingtable, []*node{})
        fmt.Print(routingtable)
    }
}
```

Comment: Take the Tour of Go which describes such stuff pretty well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply means it contains 4 empty node pointer slices, which is the expected behavior from your code.

It is a slice of slices of node pointers.

Here is a simple modification of your code to show you how it works if you add nodes to your slices:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type node struct {
    id int
}

func main() {
    var routingTable [][]*node
    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        routingTable = append(routingTable, []*node{&node{id: i}})
    }
    fmt.Print(routingTable)
}
```

Will output the slice of slices of node pointers, containing one node each with a different address:

```
[[0x10414020] [0x10414024] [0x10414028] [0x1041402c]]
```

Try it yourself [here](https://play.golang.org/p/Ly-D-4skozr)

Comment: so suppose if i enter a new variable of type node and then try to append it to the routing table then why is it throwing an error

Comment: 'code' type node struct {
 value int
}

func main() {
 var routingtable [][]*node
 for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
  new := &node{value: 3}// new line
  routingtable = append(routingtable, []*new{})
 }

 fmt.Print("routing table is ", routingtable)
}

Comment: Instead of writing `*new{}`, write `*node{new}`. Here it is working: https://play.golang.org/p/BRpvEZ0cY02